# Permissions issue with pygame installation

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to download pygame on my Mac. I had Python 3.6.0 installed and I went to the terminal (nothing else) and ran;

```
pip install pygame
```

The end of the terminal said;

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/
Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame'
```

...But I tried it anyway in IDLE and it didn't work. I figured maybe this was for Python 2 so I installed Python 2.7.15 to see if that would work. Nothing.

Am I missing a step in installation or something?

**Note:** I have tried Python 2 and it does not work. I have tried installing using;

```
pip3 install pygame
```

...and I get the same error message at the end of the terminal output.

Comment: Use a virtualenv and pip install into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use `pip3 install pygame` or `python3 -m pip install pygame` to install pygame for python 3.

The reason behind your error is because mac come with a python 2.7, so when you're using `pip`, it automatically think you're trying to install it to python2.7. But you don't have permission to that site package folder.  Since you also downloaded python3, you can use pip by typing `pip3` instead of `pip`.

If there's still a permission error, try running it as admin. For example `sudo pip3 install pygame`